# Create a list based on a character vector of names of objects

Tags: r, list

How can I create a list based on a character vector of names of objects that are themselves lists?

Minimal example

```
l1 <- list(letters, 1:10)
l2 <- list(LETTERS, 1:5)

list_names <- as.list(paste0("l", 1:2))

list(list_names)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "l1"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "l2"
```

The result is not what I want. I guess I somehow need to use backticks or soemthing such that `l1` and `l2` are not interpreted as character strings.

How would I do that?

Comment: `mget(unlist(list_names))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `mget` to return the values of the object names

```
mget(paste0('l', 1:2))
```

Comment: If I could only remember everything I've read... I forgot about `mget`..thanks thats exactly what I was looking for.